# How to run just one django test from file with VSCode?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have some tests in tests.py and want to run just one of them with VSCode easily. Of course, I can do it via command line, but I think it is possible to configure VSCode to be able to do it via GUI.

Answer (score 0):

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/unit-testing which shows two different ways to run individual tests (test explorer and test lenses).